# Creating a list with guided lines in LibreOffice

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

I created the following list using LibreOffice manually. That means I created the dotted line by pressing the dot character repeatedly (or keeping it pressed for some time) but anyway I am unable to (vertically) align the numbers properly.

[image: This is the list I manually created]

But I am sure there is an easy way to do this type of job in Microsoft Word, I did it several years ago and now forgot it.

(1) How this type of job is officially called (in MS Office)?

(2) Is the same feature available in Libre office Writer? If so, explain how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is called "**`tabstops`**" or "**`tabs`**". You can easily achieve this in LibreOffice Writer. To do so, open Menu "`Format`" -> "`Paragraph`", and select the "`Tabs`" tab.

There, you can define new tabstops (enter position, select *left* / *right* / *centered* / *decimal* alignment, select the "`Fill character`") or edit existing ones. The dotted line is created automatically depending on the "`Fill character`" you've selected:

[image]

If you need these settings often, you may define a custom paragraph style with the appropriate tabs settings.